# Why cant I parse through an array from one function into another and perform an action- in this case print a number of files?

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, loops

The first function creates an array of the Fibonacci sequence.

I want to use this array to create a number of files(index) and populate each file with the corresponding Fibonacci number(value); this is the second function.

Help with an explanation would be appreciated.
thnx

```
def fibArray(N):
    fibarray=[] 
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fibnum=0
    while find <= N:
            fibnum = (num1+num2)
            num1 = num2
            num2 = fibnum
            find = (find+1)
            fibarray.append(int(fibnum))
    return(fibarray)

def fibwritefile(fibarray):
    for X in range(len(fibarray)):
        with open(f"fib-number-{fibarray.index(X)}.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(str(fibarray[X]))
            file.close()

fibarray=fibArray(7)
fibwritefile(fibarray)
```

Comment: Explain what happens.

Comment: Prob. overcomplicate a simple thing here...

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is that .index(X) likely does not do what you are wanting. If you are trying to get the 1st element in fibarray, you would do this by fibarray[0] and not fibarray.index(0). you are iterating 0 - len(fibarray) and then trying to find that number in fibarray. Here is how I would modify the code to fix it

```
def fibArray(N):
    fibarray=[] 
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fibnum=0
    while find <= N:
            fibnum = (num1+num2)
            num1 = num2
            num2 = fibnum
            find = (find+1)
            fibarray.append(int(fibnum))
    return(fibarray)

def fibwritefile(fibarray):
    for X in range(len(fibarray)):
        with open(f"fib-number-{fibarray[X]}.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(str(fibarray[X]))
            file.close()

fibarray=fibArray(7)
fibwritefile(fibarray)
```

Comment: Hi mate thnx for the response- what the second function aims to do is create a number of files with the names of those files being the number of elements in the array. However, the contents are the value themselves- so the content of the array.